# What is addButtonName means?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I want to create a void function on my viewController.

Suddenly I have this autocomplete suggesting me to make:

```
-(void)addNearbyButton:(NSSet *)objects
```

Hmnm... What exactly this do?

All my other buttons have the same feature.

```
-(void)addMapButtonObject:(<#object-type#> *)object
```

bla bla

What is that? I never use it, but what does it should do?